# Starter for code in php5

Tags: php, linux, process

I have a php code `phpprog` under Linux, which I can start like any other normal code as

```
php5 phpprog
```

or

```
php5 phpprog&
```

with the latter to have the process run in the background. However, I want to be able to

1. start this process in the background
2. stop this process automatically, without search for the PID of the job

To achieve this, I need some other code which I call `starter` which will start the actual main process like

```
php5 starter start
```

and which stops the main process like

```
php5 starter stop
```

The name of the actual main program can be hardcoded in `starter`, and I want to have only one instance of `phpprog` runing.

Since I am not very experienced in php, I would appreciate some help in how the code `starter` might look like.

Comment: What is "starter", where did you get it, and what does it do?

Comment: This is the code in question. When I type `php5 starter start` this `starter` code starts the actual code `phpprog` in the background, like `phpprog&`. But I need to have the code `phpprog` running even if I close the terminal, log out etc. Then, to stop the running php process `phpprog` I would like to just type `php5 starter stop` to stop the process `phpprog`, without searching for the PID or anything. This should be handled by the `starter` script I am looking for.

Comment: Which operating system (distro)?

Answer (score 0):

You can write an init script. Which starts your application on system boot. You can also start/stop/restart it.

http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=2&chap=4

Comment: I need to start the script after I have copied the files directly, not after an additional reboot. Nice idea I have thought of as well, but applicable to my problem.

Comment: How often does this occur? A little bit more context about what the script actually does would be nice.

Comment: The main script serves as a kind of communication device on a new installation of the gentoo linux system. Cannot say how often this will happen, but could be once per day or even more frequent. A convenient way to copy and start some code on this new system would be very convenient. So far, starting the script with a `ssh` in connection with an ampersand (`&`) works quite ok.